# Multiple generic event publishers?

Tags: c#

I have this simple interface:

```
public interface IEventPublisher<T>
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(T report);

    public event EventHandler OnEventReceived;
}
```

Then I can write a class to subscribe to events of type int and string:

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public Subscriber(IEventPublisher<int> intPublisher, IEventPublisher<string> stringPublisher)
    {
        intPublisher.OnEventReceived += OnIntEventReceived;
        stringPublisher.OnEventReceived += OnStringEventReceived;
    }

    private void OnIntEventReceived(int report)
    {
    }

    private void OnStringEventReceived(string report)
    {
    }
}
```

Now comes the challenge: I would like to write a class to be a publisher of events of type int and string, so I start with:

```
public class Publisher : IEventPublisher<int>, IEventPublisher<string>
{
}
```

How do I implement this in order to satisfy both interfaces? The problem is that the event handler names are identical (OnEventReceived).

This is how I would have written it for a publisher just implementing one of the interfaces:

```
public interface IEventPublisher<T>
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(T report);

    public event EventHandler OnEventReceived;
}

public class Subscriber
{
    public Subscriber(IEventPublisher<int> intPublisher)
    {
        intPublisher.OnEventReceived += OnIntEventReceived;
    }

    private void OnIntEventReceived(int report)
    {
    }
}

    public class Publisher : IEventPublisher<int>
    {

        public event IEventPublisher<int>.EventHandler? OnEventReceived;

        public Publisher()
        {
            Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber(this);
        }

        private void GenerateEvents()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                ...
                OnEventReceived?.Invoke(number);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it? My IDE (with ReSharper) gives this implementation:

```
public class Publisher : IEventPublisher<int>, IEventPublisher<string>
{
    event IEventPublisher<int>.EventHandler? IEventPublisher<int>.OnEventReceived
    {
        add
        {
            // Your code here.
        }
        remove
        {
            // Your code here.
        }
    }

    event IEventPublisher<string>.EventHandler? IEventPublisher<string>.OnEventReceived
    {
        add
        {
            // Your code here.
        }
        remove
        {
            // Your code here.
        }
    }
}
```

And the Subscriber class would subscribe like this.

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public Subscriber()
    {
        var publisher = new Publisher();
        IEventPublisher<int> intPublisher = publisher;
        IEventPublisher<string> stringPublisher = publisher;
        intPublisher.OnEventReceived += OnIntEventReceived;
        stringPublisher.OnEventReceived += OnStringEventReceived;
    }

    private void OnIntEventReceived(int report)
    {
    }

    private void OnStringEventReceived(string report)
    {
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't actually tried compiling/running this.

Comment: I tried to use IntelliSense in Vs2022, but that didn't go all the way. How do you subscribe to these events from the subscriber then?

Comment: @OlavT I edited the answer for the subscription part.

Comment: Looks like it could work. How do you implement the events handler add / remove methods?

Comment: @OlavT I don't understand your question about implementation. Surely you would write whatever code you needed? I'll update the answer again.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's my code. But it's a bit unclear what that code should do as I just want to add / remove a subscriber to the event handler. So, an example would be great. When I receive an event in the Publisher, I just want to call the event handler with OnEventReceived?.Invoke(receivedInt) for example. Ideally I don't want any custom implementation of these in the first place as these should just be events handlers I could do += on.

Comment: I added the code in the original post for a publisher implementing just one of the interfaces to give you an idea on how it's wired together.